# Is Juno Not Compatible with Wacom?

Tags: settings, drivers

[image: This is my desktop System Settings look like]

If in Loki you can find the Wacom menu at System Settings, you can't see any setting related to Wacom tablet in Juno. Can someone help me to solve this? I even don't know how to install the driver. And imma designer who uses Inkscape as daily use. Thank you.

Comment: Can you try this answer posted here at [https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/16606/16827](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/16606/16827) and see if this works.

Answer (score 2):

Look, Elementary OS doesn't support Wacom Devices in the System Settings, but if you download the  Gnome-Control-Center Package you will be able to configure your Wacom Table as you would in any other Gnome distribution.

Run this command to install  Gnome-Control-Center:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

Then you just run Gnome-Control-Center with the following command:

```
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center --overview
```

Go to the Devices tab and then Wacom Tablet tab and that's it.

I hope that will be helpful and sorry i didn't see the post before.